# Unable to Add a subview to a LinearLayout with "Wrap_Content"

Tags: android-layout, android, android-linearlayout

I'm using data to build elements of a `ViewGroup`.  The `ViewGroup` are `LinearLayouts`, except the leaves, which are `TextViews`.  Because Data draws the hierarchy, I inflate the `LinearLayouts` and `TextViews` from individual XML files programatically on the fly.

**My Problem:**
When I create a `LinearLayout` with the attribute `wrap_content`, then inflate a `TextView` or other `LinearLayout` into it, I can't get the parents (or enough of them, anyway) to redraw, respecting the new view.  These `LinearLayouts` always seem to come out at 0 size, because when they are first created (before their children are inflated), they wrap around nothing.

I've tried calling some stock methods of `ViewGroup` but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please, edit your answer with some code.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't logged in before.  Below please find: Top parent XML, child layout XML, textView XML, and insertion code.  Thanks for helping me out!

Top Parent Xml
`<LinearLayout
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:id="@+id/tasks_view">
  </LinearLayout>`

Child Layout XML
`<LinearLayout
     android:orientation="vertical"
  android:id="@+id/task_line_tasks"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>`

TextView XML
`<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:textSize="10pt"
        android:layout_width="40dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#EAADEA"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>`

Insertion code:
`inflater.inflate(R.layout.person_line, tasks_view);
   newPersonLine = (LinearLayout) tasks_view.getChildAt(tasks_view.getChildCount()-1);
   newPersonLine.setId(i);
   newPersonName = (TextView)newPersonLine.getChildAt(0);
   newPersonName.setId(0);
   newPersonName.setText(people[i][0]);`